# Split String from inifile

Tags: string, ant, split, ini

i've got a question about ant and String split.
In a IniFile i've a section "[app_version]" with 1 element: "VERSION = 3.48".
My goal is to split "3.48" in 3 and 48.
I've try to read the ini file sucessfully with this code and it's work.

```
            <target name="get_new_version_number">
        <property file="${basedir}/Ini File/Config.ini" prefix="config.">
                </property>
        <property name="version_actuelle" value="${config.VERSION}" />
        <echo message="version de l'application: ${version_actuelle}"/>
```

but, how can i split "3.48" witch is my value, in 3 and 48. I need to do this to increment 48 each time i execute the script.
Thanks by advance for your considerations.
Regards.

Simon

---

thanks for your answer.
I've try your solution but it not work for me because, i've got for result, 3.48.1, 3.48.1.2, 3.48.1.2.3....... etc
I really need to increment "48" so i have to split my value 3.48 with split fonction or something else.
But, again, thanks very much for your time.
regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Ant addon **[Flaka](http://code.google.com/p/flaka)** provides a split function, f.e. =

```
<project name="demo" xmlns:fl="antlib:it.haefelinger.flaka">
 <property name="yourvalue" value="3.48"/>

 <fl:echo>#{split('${yourvalue}', '\.')[0]}${line.separator}#{split('${yourvalue}', '\.')[1]}</fl:echo>

</project>
```

if you have further requirements -- you mentioned a "need to increment" -- you have to give more details.
It's no problem to wrap it in a for loop with Flaka.

Answer (score 1):

Simplest solution would be to read the major number from the ini file and then use the [buildnumber](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/buildnumber.html) task to manage the incrementing number

```
<buildnumber/>
<echo message="${majorNum}.${build.number}"/>
```